# how to pass values to :nth-child() css selector in cypress

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, cypress

I am having a parent Div that has many sub element, while traversing thorough them if I need to select some child element I will do,

```css
cy.get(root-div > div:nth-child(1))
```

And then I have to get 2nd element I will be doing like

```css
cy.get(root-div > div:nth-child(2))
```

Can we make this `div:nth-child(2)` part dynamic something like,

```css
cy.get(root-div > div:nth-child(${0}))
```

And then pass the values when we are calling this locator? So that locator becomes dynamic and can be used for all child elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a JavaScript function for returning that string, and let it take in an indexing variable.

```js
const getNthChild(index) => {
  return `root-div > div:nth-child(${index})`
});
// In test
cy.get(getNthChild(1));
```

Additionally, if your `cy.get()` command yields multiple elements, the `cy.eq()` command can select an element at an index.

```js
cy.get('root-div > div').eq(1).should('be.visible')
cy.get('root-div > div').eq(2).should('have.text', 'foo');
```

Alternatively, you could create a custom Cypress command, although I think that is a little bit of an overkill.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getNthChild', (index) => {
  return cy.get(`root-div > div:nth-child(${index})`);
});
// In test
cy.getNthChild(1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are dealing with the children elements, you can use the `.children(selector)` command and specify the `nth` one either inside it's selector or following it with `.eq()`

Some options are

```js
// give me 2nd child that is a div
cy.get('root-div').children('div').eq(1).should(...

// same, using `eq()` inside the selector
cy.get('root-div').children('div:eq(1)').should(...

// traverse all the children, with index
cy.get('root-div').children((child, index) => {
  cy.wrap(child).should(...
```

I would not use a function or a custom command as it adds complexity but adds no extra clarity.